# Send message only to the users who are currently using the application (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm making a simple web application for organizing events and I want to add the option to send invitations only to the users who currently have the app opened in a browser. I have no idea where to start so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You could start with https://www.google.co.in/  definitely you will get something to start with. If you get stucked there again come here and ask :)

Comment: SignalR is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a full answer "how to do" but you definitely should look into ASP.NET SignalR library - http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr.

There're tons of articles on it.
Just a couple of examples:

- http://www.codemag.com/Article/1210071
- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/672433/Real-time-Notifications-with-SignalR